# Invalid request when trying to obtain access token for Google API

Tags: java, request, google-api

I am trying to obtain an access token from a Java desktop/standalone application using Apache Http:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("code").append('=').append(authorization_code)
      .append('&').append("client_id").append('=').append(client_id)
      .append('&').append("client_secret").append('=').append(client_secret)
      .append('&').append("redirect_uri").append('=').append("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob2")
      .append('&').append("grant_type").append('=').append("authorization_code");

    HttpPost httppost
        = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(sb.toString()));

    System.out.println(httppost.getURI());

    System.out.println(new String(
            EntityUtils.toByteArray(httppost.getEntity())));
    httppost.getEntity().getContent();

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    byte[] ba = EntityUtils.toByteArray(resp.getEntity());
    System.out.println(new String(ba));
```

The request URL is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

The content is:

```
code=4/uktjFRIoKS-VTwADJjO6vSYV3ZyU.Qop5zb7BIj0bOl05ti8ZT3bH57rDdgI
&client_id=128871852795.apps.googleusercontent.com
&client_secret=***********************
&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob2
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

and I get:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

I read the other similar SO questions, but it did not solve my issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you just put it in the URL bar as a `GET` request in your browser?

Comment: The docs says it has to be a POST

Comment: Ok, what if you make a dummy HTML page with a form and lots of hidden input tags that sends exactly the same data. Does that work? In other words, remove the Apache library from the equation and see if the problem is Java or something else.

Comment: I just tried with a dummy page, I have exactly the same error...

Comment: Well now you know the problem isn't with your Java code. I recommend looking at the google API again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. Actually below code

```
&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob2
```

should be

```
&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```